# Kubuntu dual boot with windows 10 you need to load the kernel first

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, kernel, kubuntu

I'm running kubuntu dual booted with windows 10 and sometimes while booting it gives me an error saying `You need to load the kernel first` I have no idea why does this happen, But if I press escape then it takes me to a shell and then on that shell if I type `exit` then it takes me back to the grub bootloader screen and I I again select an Operating system from there then it allows me to boot into that OS, Can someone please help me with this?
P.S - I'm a newbie when it comes to linux

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing Grub Customizer; this gives you a range of other things you can tweak and might fix your problem: [How to Install Grub Customizer in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS - Tips on Ubuntu](https://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/03/11/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-18-04-lts/).

Comment: But can you please explain a little about what could be possibly causing this problem?

Comment: @ansme I think that it could be caused by Grub that isn't configured properly. Resaving your configuration by using grub-customizer could fix your problem, it's something worth trying :)

Comment: okay thank you I'll try that :)